# ratio distribution of gamma with different parameter

Tags: probability-distributions, gamma-function, ratio

Let $X$ be gamma distributed random variable with parameters $a$ and $b$. Let $W$ be gamma distributed random variable with parameters $c$ and $d$, such that
\begin{equation}
f_X(x) = \frac{x^{a-1}e^{-\frac{x}{b}}}{b^a\Gamma(a)}\quad \text{and} \quad f_W(w) = \frac{w^{c-1}e^{-\frac{w}{d}}}{d^c\Gamma(c)}.
\end{equation}

The problem is to find the distribution of $\frac{X}{W+s}$ where $s$ is a constant. So far I have got,
Let $Z = \frac{X}{W+s} = \frac{X}{Y}$, such that the CDF of $Z$ now can be stated as.
\begin{equation}
\int_s^{\infty}\int_{0}^{yz}\frac{x^{a-1}e^{\frac{-x}{b}}(y-s)^{(c-1)}e^{\frac{-(y-s)}{d}}}{b^a\Gamma(a)d^c\Gamma(c)}\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y
\end{equation}

Integrating the following will yield in
\begin{equation}
1-\int_{s}^{\infty}\frac{\Gamma_{inc}(a,\frac{yz}{b})(y-s)^{(c-1)}e^{-\frac{y-s}{d}}}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(c)d^c}\mathrm{d}y
\end{equation}
where $\Gamma_{inc}$ is the incomplete gamma function.

I could not solve the integral term. Is there any way to solve it, or even any other way the problem of finding the distribution of $Z$.

Comment: The inclusion of parameter _s_ makes the answer rather more messy - but it is possible to derive a solution.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The 's' makes life more difficult. Are there any other ways to bypass the final 'weird' integral or even proceed a different way? I tried with X and W to be exponential and it somehow comes up with clean solution. So I believe the CDF method is correct in here.

Comment: I don't think the CDF method will do the trick here (not for me, anyway). I'll post a solution later when I have a chance.

Answer (score 2):

**pdf of .... Ratio of Gamma to shifted Gamma**

Let $X \sim \text{Gamma}(a,b)$ with pdf $f(x)$:

[image]

Let $W \sim \text{Gamma}(c,d)$ be independent of $X$ and define parameter $s>0$. Then, $W+s$ has a shifted Gamma distribution. Then, by any of the usual methods, the pdf of $Y = \frac{\large1}{\large W+s}$ is $g(y)$:

[image]

We seek the pdf of $Z = \frac{\large X}{\large W+s} = X*Y$. As this is just the product of two independent random variables, ... the solution pdf, say $h(z)$ is given immediately by:

[image]

where I am using the `TransformProduct` function from the *mathStatica* package for *Mathematica* to do the nitty-gritties.

All done.

**Monte Carlo check**

It's always a good idea to check symbolic output. Here is a quick Monte Carlo simulation of the 'empirical' pdf of $Z = \frac{\large X}{\large W+s}$ (the jagged BLUE curve) compared to the theoretical solution $h(z)$ (the RED curve) derived above, when:

```
 params = {a -> 2.3, b -> 3, c -> 4, d -> 5, s -> 7}
```

[image]

Looks fine.

**Notes**

1. For detail on the `Hypergeometric1F1Regularized` function, see:  http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hypergeometric1F1Regularized.html
2. As disclosure, I should perhaps add that I am one of the authors of the software used above.
3. The solution above works for real values of parameter $a$ (but not for integer values). The problem with integer values is some odd manifestation of the way *Mathematica* simplifies or converts certain Gamma functions into trig funcs, if I recall correctly.

Comment: Can you also give the expression for CDF using mathStatica @wolfies ?